# Is there a method to use FIDO2/webauthn with ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, webauthn, fido

As the title says.

We use ssh to connect to many sites and would like to move to use FIDO2/webauthn for authentication.

Is this possible?
What tools do we need?

We are using ubuntu as the client and server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve FIDO2-like multi-factor authentication when ssh'ing into a server if you combine a FIDO2-compatible security key with `ecdsa-sk` keys. The trick is to generate a new keypair with the `ecdsa-sk` (the "sk" is for "security key") and the flag that requires you to enter the security key's PIN as well:

```
$> ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sk -C <email address> -O verify-required
```

Enter your security key's PIN when prompted, then skip the prompt to password-protect the keypair (the security key and its PIN will protect its use instead). Finally, specify the absolute file path to save the keypair to.

You'll end up with a private key and public key as you'd expect. Add the **.pub** file to https://github.com/settings/keys as an **authentication** key, then update **~/.ssh/config** to tell it to use the corresponding private key:

```
Host github.com
  IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/name-you-gave-keypair-here
```

To test that everything is working fine, you can attempt to ssh into GitHub:

```bash
$> ssh -T git@github.com
```

You should see something like this:

> Hi UsernameHere! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

And there you have it - security key-backed multi-factor authentication for your SSH connections.

One last thing, you'll need to be using at least OpenSSH 8.2 on both server and client side as it's the earliest version that support `ecdsa-sk` keypairs.

Comment: I wrote a whole post about this over on my blog, including some troubleshooting steps that felt like too much to try and put into the answer. Check it out if the steps above don't work out for you: https://blog.millerti.me/2021/05/16/strengthen-github-ssh-access-with-fido2s-pin-support/